# Movie in MS-Paint?

Tags: windows, windows-media-player, microsoft-paint

I ran movie in media player and I pressed Print screen key and pasted screenshot in MS-Paint then I was shocked that movie was playing in MS-Paint. I want to know that how can possible this???

Comment: Does someone have a video or gif that demonstrates this? I have a hard time picturing this in my head.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT: Opps, misread the question.

Windows Media player draws images on the screen in a special way. This stops you from taking screenshots, but has the side effect of being able to see video in MSPaint

Comment: Yes, this happens in some applications. (It's like an optical illusion.. :))

Comment: To be more precise -- it puts the movie in the graphic card memory region which is directly send to monitor, so in the layer above all Windows windows. Than it moves and clips movie to reflect its window position and positions of other, overlapping windows. Sometimes it fails, as in this question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this has to do with hardware acceleration. If you have a movie player that has hardware acceleration enabled and you have another type of graphic app in the same region this can happen. I haven't noticed it in quite a while. If this is a problem for you, you can go in the windows media player options and turn off hardware acceleration.

Look in options -> performance. Either as hardware acceleration or "turn on direct X video acceleration". Unless you're playing HD content and had hardware that contributed a lot, you might not notice much of a performance difference and if I remember right it should take care of the problem.

Also, as Lord.Quackstar stated, you can't take screenshots of the video. But if you turn off hardware acceleration you can.